# 96 GB RAM on a Dell T7500 showing up as 78GB in Ubuntu Server 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, memory

Running Ubuntu Server 11.04.  I've got a new Dell Precision T7500 workstation loaded up with 12x8GB DIMMs and the BIOS shows 96GB but checking /proc/meminfo gives:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
MemTotal:       82650584 kB
```

and free gives:

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         80713       5254      75459          0         89       3304
-/+ buffers/cache:       1860      78852
Swap:        95365          2      95363
```

The Win7 install that it came with showed 96GB with 80 GB usable, as well.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /var/log/dmesg | grep Memory`

Comment: Ensure that you are running the latest BIOS update. I'm not saying that's your solution but it's probably a good starting point...

Comment: What is the output of `dmidecode -t 16 -t 17`?

Comment: cat /var/log/dmesg | grep Memory
[    0.000000] Memory: 82641428k/84672512k available (5510k kernel code, 788924k absent, 1242160k reserved, 3122k data, 812k init)

Comment: and the dmidecode: http://pastebin.com/axGdhXvq

Comment: also, Dell was more than happy to sell the same machine with a 12*16GB configuration, so I don't think the BIOS would be crapping out.

Comment: Wild guess - unplug as much as possible devices from the motherboard and see if this changes anything. I have seen old MBs reserving memory for itself. It shouldn't happen, but ... who knows.

Comment: Hmm, there's nothing really plugged into it to remove.  This is a brand new motherboard, too.  Is it possible that the low-end AMD graphics card it shipped with somehow reserved 16 gigs of RAM for itself?

Comment: What is the video card that came with it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the kernel-parameter "mem=96G" ?

Answer (score 1):

We're run into a few problems with RAM and/or Video memory addressing across a few iterations of Dell hardare where I work and found the solution to be adding pci=nommconf as a kernel option in grub - worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using two CPUs? If this workstation got 18 slots and you're only getting use of 9 out of 12 memory sticks working. It almost sounds like you're only using 1 CPU. Other than that, there might be failure in your motherboard / firmware.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Memory Mode in BIOS to "Optimizer" so all memory is available to the operating system.

Possible of memory mode selections:

- Optimizer Mode — mode uses Independent channel configuration for highest memory subsystem 
  performance. This is the default ordering configuration choice.
- Advanced ECC Mode — RAS feature that extends multi-bit single device error correction to x8 
  DRAMs, which runs pairs of memory channels in lockstep mode. There can be a substantial hit to 
  memory performance when using this mode.
- Spare Mode — RAS feature that allocates one rank per channel as a spare to reduce the likelihood 
  of correctable errors from becoming uncorrectable errors, but at a cost to memory capacity.
- Mirror Mode — RAS feature with paired memory channels that provide data and transmission 
  fault-tolerance, but available memory capacity is reduced by 50 percent and system memory 
  bandwidth will decline.